# cannot get a parameter from a inherited model in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my django models I have a class called Admin

```
class Admin(User):

number = models.IntegerField()

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Admin, self).__init__()
    self.is_staff = True
    self.is_superuser = True
```

and in my view I have:

```
admin = admin.objects.get(id=1)
```

and when I say `print(admin.number)` or `return HttpResponse(admin.number)` it returns None but I have already created this record and it has a number

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing any of the parameters up to the superclass. That means they'll never be set when the object is created, which includes when it's retrieved from the database.

You should do:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Admin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```